# Integration by complex exponential, extra term in argument of trig function

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-numbers, indefinite-integrals

I am trying to understand how best to integrate the following form using the complex exponential:

$\int(e^{ax}cos(b+cx)dx$

where a, b, c are real numbers.

I'm familiar with a method using the real part (or imaginary part) of a complex number. I have used this for the form:

$\int(e^{ax}cos(cx)dx$

but I run into trouble using this process with the first form due to the extra term $b$, from which I cannot factor out $x$ when it comes to:

$Real [ \int(e^{ax+(b+cx)i})dx]
$

I am not sure whether it is correct to keep the $e^{b}$ term separate, and integrate it in its own right, being as it represents a multiplier that is entirely real.

Comment: Sub $u= b+cx$ first and then apply your method?

Comment: Don't forget the $i$

Comment: Thanks @Randall. I have tried substitution, but then in expressing all x expressions in terms of u I find I have the same problem. I.e. i end up with a power of e that is not purely a multiple of u, but contains an extra term.

Comment: Thanks @ClaudeLeibovici

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternative method for solving $\int e^{ax}\cos(b+cx)dx$ by complex numbers. As you know
\begin{align}
\int e^{ax}\cos(b+cx)dx &= \mathbf{Re}\int e^{ax+(b+cx)i}dx \\
&= \mathbf{Re}\,e^{bi}\dfrac{e^{(a+ci)x}}{a+ci} \\
&= \mathbf{Re}\,\dfrac{a-ci}{a^2+c^2}e^{ax}e^{(b+cx)i} \\
&= \dfrac{e^x}{a^2+c^2}\Big(a\cos(b+cx)+c\sin(b+cx)\Big)
\end{align}

Comment: I think you mean:
$$\dfrac{\color{red}{e^{ax}}}{a^2+c^2}\Big(a\cos(b+cx)+c\sin(b+cx)\Big)$$

Comment: yes. thanks!...

Comment: Thanks @MyGlasses. This has helped to resolve the awkward arrangement of the power. If I understand correctly I need the power in terms of a multiple of x in order to integrate, so I separate the e^(bi) term which can be taken outside the integral as a complex coefficient. Post-integration this term can be absorbed into the result and the answer expressed in cartesian form.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: using two times Integration by parts we get $$\frac{e^{a x} (a \cos (b+c x)+c \sin (b+c x))}{a^2+c^2}$$

Comment: Thanks, I had tried integration by parts but I think I do not then reach the solution primarily by use of the complex exponential method.